# rails sass @import is not finding the file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I am trying to set up rails with sass,
I have remove the require tree and trying to @import the files to the application.css the following

```
@import '_variables.scss';
```

is working, any other @import I am trying to do is not working.

example

```
@import '_layout.scss'
```

is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You don't include the `.scss` or the `_`

Try: `@import "layout"`

Do some reading on http://sass-lang.com/guide, it will explain how `@import` works, and what that `_` does (these files are called "partials")

Comment: Not relevant to the question:  `@import "foo";` and `@import "_foo.scss";` are equivalent (barring naming conflicts).